# В конец динамического массива добавить еще один элемент

Tags: c++

Проблема в том, что само название динамического массива (если возможно конечно) не изменять. Не могу разобраться когда удалять старый массив.
Вот скрин кода:

Вот мой код:

```
int* sot(int* p, int, int, int** sum);
void print(int* p, int);
int main() {
    system("color 0F");
    srand(time(NULL));
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ukr");
    int a = 5;
    cin >> a;
    int* p = new int[a];
    int** sum = &p;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        *(p + i) = rand() % 10;
    }
    print(p, a);
    cout << endl;
    int b;
    cin >> b;
    sot(p, a, b, sum);
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        *(p + i) = rand() % 10;
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Функции]

Comment: Что в данном случае значит "не работает"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что требовалось от программы, то вот её правленый код:

```
int* extendedArray( int*, int, int );
void printArray( int*, int );

int main() {

    /* INITIALIZATION */
    system( "color 0F" );
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    setlocale( LC_ALL, "ukr" );
    int arraySize = 5;

    /* FIRST ARRAY INPUT */
    cout << "Input the array size:" "\n";
    cin >> arraySize;
    int* p = new int[arraySize];
    int* secondArray = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
        p[ i ] = rand() % 10;

    printArray( p, arraySize );

    /* EXTENDING OF THE FIRST ARRAY */
    int newValue;
    cout << "Input the value to add into your array:" "\n";
    cin >> newValue;

    secondArray = extendedArray( p, arraySize, newValue );
    delete[] p;

    /* Now p is the pointer to new array */
    p = secondArray;

    /* We won't use secondArray anymore */
    secondArray = 0;
    ++arraySize;

    printArray( p, arraySize );

    /* QUIT THE PROGRAM */
    system( "pause" );
}

int* extendedArray( int* A, int arraySize, int newValue )
{
    int *newArray = new int[ arraySize + 1 ];

    for ( int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i )
        newArray[ i ] = A[ i ];

    newArray[ arraySize ] = newValue;

    return newArray;
}

void printArray( int* p, int arraySize )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i )
        cout << p[ i ] << " ";

    cout << endl;

}
```